# Sequence of decimals in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

How can I print decimals between 0 and 1 in an Excel spreadsheet?

E.g) I have a sequence of numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make more sense.

Comment: I guess you should refine your question _a little bit_

Answer (score 1):

Try "=1/10" in one cell, "=2/10" in the cell below that, and then AutoFill by dragging the fill-handle down ten (or eight in this case) rows for that one column.